# Update полученных данных (AJAX) JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. Только начал изучение AJAX. Нужно отредактировать данные, которые летят с сервера. Я их получаю, заполняю инпуты, а как сохранить (изменить) не пойму, могу только добавить как новую запись..но нужно отредактировать.

```js
$('.edit-table').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
         $('#modal-1').modal();
         $('.btn-form').css({
             'display': 'none'
         });
         $('.btn-form-save').css({
             'display': 'inline-block'
         });
         
         $.ajax({
            url:'/api/v1/education/direction_info/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = data[0];
//                debugger;
                for (key in obj) {
                    console.log(key, obj[key])
                    
                    
                    
                   if(key.indexOf('image') != -1) {
                       $("form[name='form03'] [name='" + key + "']").attr('value', obj[key]);
                   } else { 
                       $("form[name='form03'] [name='" + key + "']").val(obj[key]);
                   }
                }
                
            }
        });  
     });
```

```html
<table class="table" data-token="{{ csrf_token }}">
                                 <thead class="table-inverse">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Направление</th>
                                        <th>Руководитель</th>
                                        <th>Кол-во программ</th>
                                        <th>Кол-во слушателей</th>
                                        <th>
                                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-1" class="btn btn-primary mrg-b-lg  pull-right  add-prod  js-direct">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>Add product</a>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                     {% for obj in object_list %}
                                        <tr data-href="{{ obj.url }}">
                                            <td>{{ obj.pk }}</td>
                                            <td><a href="{{ obj.get_lk_url }}">{{ obj.name }}</a></td>
                                            <td>{{ obj.director }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ obj.get_courses_count }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ obj.get_students_count }}</td>
                                            <td class="td-center">
                                           <a href="#" class="table-link  edit-table  js-direct" data-id="{{ obj.pk }}">
                                            <span class="fa-stack">
                                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                            </span>
                                           </a>
                                            <a href="#" class="table-link danger  unistall-table  js-direct" data-id="{{ obj.pk }}">
                                                <span class="fa-stack">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

<form role="form" name="form03" class="form-list" data-token="{{ csrf_token }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name1">Направление</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name1" name="name" placeholder="Введите направление">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="sort1">Сортировка</label>
       <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sort1" name="sort" min=1 max=100 placeholder="Введите число от 1 до 100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="check1">Архив</label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="archived" id="check1">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="image1">image</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image1">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="instructor_image">instructor_page_image</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="instructor_page_image" id="instructor_image">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="popular">Популярность</label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="popular" id="popular">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="director1">Директор</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="director" id="director1">
                                
                            </select>
      </div>
      
     </form>
```

Comment: У вас у записи нету уникального айди разве? Когда высылаете данные обратно на сервер, высылаете айди записи и на сервере проверяйте - если есть с таким айди запись - то перезаписываете, если айди нету (не пришел) - создаете новую запись. Если же это АПИ и оно ваше - создайте метод PUT который будет перезаписывать данные. В вашем примере нету того как вы их сохраняете. Приведите еще этот код.

Comment: @Moonvvell как раз с сохранением и проблема. Да есть конечно id у каждой записи: var id = $(this).data('id');

Comment: У вас идут запросы к АПИ. У вас у апи должен быть адрес на котором идет перезапись измененной записи. Сделайте кнопку которая будет высылать на этот адрес данные которые вы изменили уже. А как вы добавляете новую запись ? ПРи нажатии изменить - у вас подгружаются данные с АПИ. СДелайте так чтобы при нажатии на сейв - высланы были данные на метод АПИ которых сохраняет их

Comment: @Moonvvell т.е. мне сделать Ajax запрос в Ajax запросе? или как записать эти сохраненные данные?

Comment: Один запрос для получения данных в таблицу. Он уже у вас есть. В примере. Второй - при нажатии кнопки - сохранить (или какой либо другой). Нажали сохранить - ушел второй запрос на сервер с измененными данными.

Comment: @Moonvvell т.е. $.ajax ({ существующий запрос, success: function() { существующий код; $.ajax({ новый запрос отправки измененных данных на сервер...... }) } });

Comment: т.е. $('#СОХРАНИ_МЕНЯ').on('click', function(){$.ajax({ТУТ НОВЫЕ ДАННЫЕ ВЫСЫЛАЕТЕ НА АПИ АДРЕС});});

Comment: @Moonvvell ага это понял, но этот запрос делаю в success существующего, да?

Comment: Отдельно :) Отдельная функция, которая будет срабатывать при нажатии кнопки сохранить. Функцию что вы привели в вопросе - и функция записи будут ОТДЕЛЬНЫ друг от друга. Независимы. Там при нажатии кнопки вы чтото делаете, и здесь при нажатии кнопки - чтото будет делатся. В нашем случае - записыватся данные

Comment: @Moonvvell теперь понял. В новом запросе же нужно получить отредактированные данные, как их передать из функции РЕДАКТИРОВАТЬ в новый запрос СОХРАНИТЬ?

Comment: Та никак. Они у вас же в инпутах будут записанны. Читаете данные из инпутов и высылаете. У вас же вон есть форма - данные уже в ней. Ее и высылаете. Если не знаете как - почитайте про сериализацию формы и как ее выслать на сервер с помощью ajax

Comment: @Moonvvell вот теперь все понял) спасибо) да сериализовать то умею уже)